# Cannot read property 'files' of undefined for sending multiple images

Tags: reactjs, image

## Code

```
class Add_Give_Item_Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      //   #インプット情報用
      info: {
        name: '',
        owner: '',
        keyword1: '',
        keyword2: '',
        keyword3: '',
        bland: '',
        state: '未使用、新品',
        category: '',
        images: [],
        detail: '',
      },
      //   Validation用
      // 　urlは必須項目ではないのでValidationには含めない
      message: {
        name: '',
        keyword1: '',
        keyword2: '',
        keyword3: '',
        state: '',
        category: '',
        detail: '',
      },
      allCategory: null,
      allBland: null,
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleImageSelect = this.handleImageSelect(this);
  }


////
...
////


handleChange = (e) => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    const { info, message } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      info: { ...info, [name]: value },
    });
    this.setState({
      message: { ...message, [name]: this.validator(name, value) },
    });
  };

  handleImageSelect = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      info: { ...this.state.info, images: [...this.state.info.images, e.target.files] },
    });
  };


  render() {
    const { info, message, allCategory, allBland } = this.state;
    // setStateが完了するまではnullにする。
    if (this.state.allCategory === null || this.state.allBland === null) {
      return <CircularProgress />;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          
         ///////

          .....

         ///////


          <label>Images</label>
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.handleImageSelect} />
```

## What I want to do

I would like to catch each file sent by a user and put into `state` as `this.state.info.images` which is an array.

I saw some questions on stackoverflow and then I found some solutions. When I wrote the same code as what I saw, I got an error like below.

```
cannot read property files of undefined
```

I should write the same code but I got the error for some reasons.
I may take another way to realize what I want to do, but I want to write readable codes and figure out why it is happening.

I would like you to teach me why this happens and solutions.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I just notice I didn't put `bind` with `this.handleImageSelect = this.handleImageSelect(this)`.

Now it works well.

Thank you very much.